# Do something after getting result jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Am I blind or is there not possibility to do something after gettings results in jQuery UI Autocompelete?

This what I'm trying: user starts writing address in input field, Autocomplete gets suggestions and all those suggestions what the Autocomplete shows, should be showed on a map. The showing on map part I can do but how can I trigger it when the Autocomplete gets results? I saw there was "Select"-event and such but no "search-suggestions-are-ready"-event. How should I do it then? Any suggestions.

The js now:

```
$("form#search .address").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: addresses.php,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {term: request.term},
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.addy
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
```

All help appcreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `open` event, it occurs when the suggestion window is opened (meaning the results were already given).